# Spring view order of filters that are not security filters

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to view all registered filter chains and their order. I can see can do this using FilterChainProxys method getFilterChains() but that is only for security based ones. I would like to view the non security based filters too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot then you can enable trace logging for [`org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletContextInitializerBeans.html) and you would see logs like below which provide you the filters and there order ( security/non-security related filters)

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans: TRACE
```

You would see something like below on startup

```
    2021-12-06 23:00:55.796 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Filter initializer bean 'securityFilterChainRegistration'; order=-100, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:55.797 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:55.797 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'h2Console'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.008 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.009 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-10000, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.011 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'formContentFilter'; order=-9900, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.011 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'requestContextFilter'; order=-105, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.011 TRACE 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'corsFilter'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/shailendra/config/CorsConfig.class]
    2021-12-06 23:00:56.024 DEBUG 25652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: springSecurityFilterChain urls=[/*], characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*], hiddenHttpMethodFilter urls=[/*], formContentFilter urls=[/*], requestContextFilter urls=[/*], corsFilter urls=[/*]
```